# get post meta for all id

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I want to get all brands from DB. It should work like `get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'make', true);` but without id. It should contain an array with all brands. Which command I should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below query.

```
global $wpdb;
$make = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'make' ");
```

**Update**

```
global $wpdb;
$makes = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'make' ",ARRAY_A);
$makes = $wpdb->get_col( $makes );
$makes = implode( ',', $makes );
```

Comment: it's dispalying as array but when I'm imploding it, it says `Recoverable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in`

Comment: How do you do it? Share code.

Comment: `global $wpdb;
$makes = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'make' ");
$makes = implode($makes);
echo $makes;`

Comment: Thanks. I changed post_id to meta_value in your answer